# Kubectl logs does not return any output

Tags: python, kubernetes, logging

I am trying to debug my application and I need to look the logs for my backend service. I run it with conda run and the configuration is the following:

```
# Partir de l’image officielle de Python 3.7
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

EXPOSE 50051

# Mettre le code de l’application dans le répertoire / de l’image
WORKDIR /

# Copier les librairie nécessaire à votre application
ADD prod-env.yml /

# Installer les packages Python nécessaires dans requirements.txt
RUN conda env create -f prod-env.yml --prefix ./env

# Copier le code de l’application dans le répertoire /
ADD src /src

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
# Lancer le script app.py quand le container démarre
CMD ["conda","run", "--no-capture-output", "-v", "-v" ,"-p", "./env", "python", "-u", "-m", "src.main"]
```

I know the kubernetes deployment is successful since I am able to  send some requests and get responses, but I am trying to debug an edge case and I need the logs.
The command `kubectl logs backend-xxxxxxxx` does not return anything.

What is weird is when I try to run the container directly, I get the expected output

```
docker run --platform linux/amd64 865959cfcf1c  
DEBUG conda.gateways.logging:set_verbosity(246): verbosity set to 2
DEBUG conda.gateways.subprocess:subprocess_call(85): executing>> /bin/bash /tmp/tmpxsyy9ay5
WARNING: overwriting environment variables set in the machine
overwriting variable PYTHONUNBUFFERED
Server started, listening on 50051
```

How can I get the output when the container is deployed on kubernetes ?

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by specifying to use stdout instead of stderr in the logging config. It is weird though since the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) specifies that both stderr and stdout should be logged.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).